# Telerik Reporting: Repeat a page containing 2 graphs and a table

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I need to build a report (in Visual Studio) that takes an ObjectDataSource, and groups the data into separate pages.  Each page needs to contain 2 graphs and a table that deal with that particular group of data.

How can I approach this?  There is some documentation on page breaks on groups in a table, but my pages need to contain charts as well.  Is there a demo that shows how to build what I need?

Eventually I will also need to add this report into a ReportBook, but first things first.

Comment: It's hard to find demo on report because its mainly gui. You can find video but they will be on something precise. Not general work flow.

Comment: My way to do this is to create an exel that represent the final document I want with the basic presentation. No accurate date. Just here general information, here a char pie, here same chart pie for an other "row". Each time i find something that repeat its a Sub report. every time i got general information then detail its a sub report. Every thing turn out to be block of sub report in a report. I simplier block of report to test my skill. In a block i start by the deeper sub report.

Comment: here is the quick Step I use. I will provide an answer on how to design a report for a bill. you will mange to transphorm some of the grid into charts n things.

Comment: Is this your 1rst report? Do you know about report parameters ? And can you create a simple grid with a data source? I need to restrain the question and tutorial or it will be to broad, if it take me too mutch time I won't do it .

Comment: @PierreLebon I've created single page reports before, binding tables and graphs directly to their own ObjectDataSource.  Haven't worked with subreports yet.

Comment: Its the same. Just some name can be weird in the begining. AS a sub report can be the placeholde of a sub report in a sub report. Sub report is the name in the documentation for both the real sub report and the place hold in the parent report. But behind that it's really simple. The doc is really clear about it give it a try. I will post answer tomorow as I'm already out of the office.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly this should be straightforward:

1. Create a new report
2. Add a group definition to group the data into the two distinct groups that you want to display. *[Careful here because if you don't define your groups correctly, you could end up with more than 2 pages] Use a Boolean or "greater than" and "less than or equal" (or vice versa) are your best bets.*
3. Size the Group Details section to be the size of the page you want (8.5"x11" or whatever fits on "one page")
4. Insert a Panel into the Group Details section and expand it to be the same size as the Group Details section
5. Anchor the panel to all sides, and set the CanGrow and CanShrink properties to "false"
6. Inside the Panel add your Graphs and Table and bind to the grouped data
7. Set the Page Break property of the Group Footer to:  "After" to separate the data into two pages

Comment: I got this set up, but it's generating a page for each item in the groups, instead of one page per group of data.  I didn't see a group details section, so I put the panel in the detailSection.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: Seems to work if I move the graph and table into the group header though